# Looking for $\dim _{K}(m_{(0,0,0)}/m_{(0,0,0)}^{2})$ for certain algebraic variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $X=V(X_{2}^{2}-X_{0}^{2}X_{1},X_{1}^{3}-X_{0}^{4},X_{0}^{3}-X_{1}X_{2},X_{1}^{2}-X_{0}X_{2})\subseteq\mathbb{A}^{3}_{K}$. We denote
$$
m_{(0,0,0)}=\{\overline{f}\in K[X]:f(0,0,0)=0\},
$$
where $K[X]=K[X_{0},X_{1},X_{2}]/I(X)$. I have to show that 
$$
\dim _{K}(m_{(0,0,0)}/m_{(0,0,0)}^{2})=3.
$$
If I am not wrong, $m_{(0,0,0)}/m_{(0,0,0)}^{2}$ is the cotangent space of $X$ at $(0,0,0)$, so I have to prove that the dimension of the tangent space of $X$ at $(0,0,0)$ is $3$.

The elements of $m_{(0,0,0)}/m_{(0,0,0)}^{2}$ are of the kind 
$$
[(a_{0}X_{0}+a_{1}X_{1}+a_{2}X_{2})+I(X)]+m_{(0,0,0)}^{2},
$$
where $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}\in K$. According to this,
$\dim _{K}(m_{(0,0,0)}/m_{(0,0,0)}^{2})\leq 3$

Now, I have proved that
$$
I(X)=(X_{2}^{2}-X_{0}^{2}X_{1},X_{1}^{3}-X_{0}^{4},X_{0}^{3}-X_{1}X_{2},X_{1}^{2}-X_{0}X_{2}),
$$
but this ideal is hard to work with, and I haven't been able to prove the sought equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent space to $X$ at $O$ is given by the intersection in $K^3$of the linear subvarieties $$\sum_{i=1}^3\frac { \partial f}{\partial x_i}(O)\cdot x_i=0$$ where $f$ runs through the polynomials defining $X$.
Since your equations have no linear part the displayed equations reduce to $0=0$ and the tangent space to $X$ at $O$ is thus the whole ambient vector space $K^3$, which has of course dimension $3$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, is it true that  $m_{(0,0,0)}/m_{(0,0,0)}^{2}$ is the cotangent space of $X$ at $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. For emphasis it is also called Zariski's cotangent space, in order to emphasize that it is a purely algebraic notion, perfectly defined over fields of positive characteristic and also for non smooth algebraic varieties. Another advantage of the definition is that it is completely intrinsic, independent of any embedding in affine space. However the cotangent space  **is** easier to compute if, as in your example, the variety is embedded in affine space.